# Cordova: how to open external url in the application without opening a new browser?

Tags: cordova

I use Cordova 6.3.

I tried many methods to open an external url while loading content in cordova

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');       
        window.open('https://google.com', '_self ', 'location=yes');        
        navigator.app.loadUrl('https://www.google.com', { openExternal:false });
    },
```

It keeps on opening NEW browser !

How to open a external url inside the app ?

Comment: open the url in iframe .

Comment: I tried; I got Refused to frame 'https://www.culture-generale.fr/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' data:

Comment: Keep in mind that if you want to load external url in place of your Cordova page, it would replace it and effectively becomes a new "driver". It can access all Cordova functionality then, and be highly insecure. I think, Cordova implementation defends itself from allowing doing that, but I'm not sure exactly. InAppBrowser plugin exists exactly to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

How about using the InAppBrowser plugin?

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/

I have used it in my Cordova application - very easy to use.

Comment: yes: that works. BUT... when you add admob, the inAppBrowser goes on TOP of the admob and hide it ! SO that's not a good solution for me since I need to display ad !

Comment: First of all, I am not supposed to guess that you want to use Admob. When you ask for help, provide as much information as you can to help people who are trying to help you. Next thing, from a quick google search I found a plugin which seemingly allows you to use admob with cordova apps. I would suggest having a look at that; keep in mind you are not developing a native mobile app, neither are you developing a website, you are developing a hybrid application, and as such, most of the 3rd party library equivalents will be provided to you as plugins.

Comment: I tried almost all admob. The interstertail ads display correct. The other do not since inapbrowser puts a new browser at the TOP of the application. The inappbrowser is a good solution for facebook login for instance (it opens a browser on top, then once loggedon closes it and closes it at the end)

Comment: I'm not going to piece all the bits of information you give me to try and get a decent question. Improve your question, make everything clear and then I can help. Where do you want to display ads - in your browser? In your app? What is the problem, that you want to display a web page without opening an external browser and without it going over the rest of your application? It's not clear at all.

Answer (score 0):

***Definition and Usage***

> The replace() method replaces the current document with a new one.
>
> The difference between this method and assign(), is that replace()
>   removes the URL of the current document from the document history,
>   meaning that it is not possible to use the "back" button to navigate
>   back to the original document.

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Replace document</button>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        location.replace("http://www.w3schools.com")
    }
    </script>
```

try this hopefully that will help you .

Comment: NOT good: that opens a NEW browser !
I al talking about a cordova application !